# Population density and Circles (to represent earthquakes) on the same Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, highcharts, jvectormap

I need to create a Map to compare the **population density** of a country (e.g. USA at county -or state- level) and the epicenter of some **earthquakes** to see how many people could have felt those quakes.

The problem is that I can't find a way to put these 2 things on the same map.

In a db I have some earthquakes taken from USGS and the population data taken from Census.gov.

I was able to map earthquakes (coordinates lat/lng) with circles thanks to the Google Maps API but without population density.

I also created a map with Highcharts (Highmaps) to display population density, but I can't put circles on that because lat/lng points are not supported.

I also read about vectorWorkz and jVectorMap but couldn't find examples.

Is there a way to do such thing?  I'm not an expert so if someone has a solution or could provide me a little example I would be eternally grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jVectorMap suits all your needs. Here is an [example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/) of regions density and markers visualisation on the same map.

Comment: jVectorMap is very useful. I'm creating a multimap with drill-down functionality, but I was only able to modify the style of the main map. Can you tell me how to modify the style of the submap, please?